# Connect a web service through remote computer IP

Tags: server, proxy, static, connection, ip

We have a Windows 2019 server located at static IP of XXX. I want to develop a .net application with Visual Studio on my development machine located at dynamic IP of YYY. My application needs to connect a third party web service but connection is only accessible to IP XXX, which is our server machine. What might be the best option to develop the application on my own pc. (I don't want to install Visual Studio to the server and develop through remote desktop)
Please advice, thanks.